# can we do any kind of password protection or encryption in folder of a container in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to give access control based on the folder inside the container on the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 . Can someone please help me out on this one by giving a quick walkthrough on it?

I've tried by doing it Azure key vault but it protects the whole container .I want only to protect the folders inside a container.

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can control access to specific folders inside a container on Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using Access Control Lists (ACLs) or Role-Based Access Control (RBAC).
You can follow below procedure:
Go to the specific folder Right click the object and select Manage ACL

[image]

In the Access permission tab click on Add service principal to add the specified user or group to give control of access

[image]

Add the service principal and give the permissions regarding to your requirement and click on save button

[image]

For more information you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-acl-azure-portal) .